# adding attributes to quote items via config

Tags: attributes, configuration, onepage-checkout, quote

can someone tell me what the purpose of this is in the config?

```
<sales>
    <quote>
        <item>
            <product_attributes>
                <sku/>
                <type_id/>
                <name/>
                <status/>
                <visibility/>
                <price/>
                <weight/>
                <url_path/>
                <url_key/>
                <thumbnail/>
                <small_image/>
                <tax_class_id/>
                <special_from_date/>
                <special_to_date/>
                <special_price/>
                <cost/>
                <is_recurring/>
                <recurring_profile/>
                <gift_message_available/>
                <msrp_enabled/>
                <msrp/>
                <msrp_display_actual_price_type/>
            </product_attributes>
        </item>
    </quote>
</sales>
```

i understand that it has something to do with adding attributes to the quote item, and that you can add your own attributes using this method.

does it have to do with collections?

i'm going through the Magento OnePage Checkout class, and the exercise is to use a converter to add an attribute to the quote and order items. it suggested using an observer to get the product attribute to the quote item (which i did), and using a converter to get it to the order item.

i had it working even before i added the attribute in the config (like above), so not sure where this config comes into play.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. it's so that the product attribute is available in the sales module. not all product attributes are available when you get a product within a quote.